# How to add double quotes around string and number pattern?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Hi I need to add double quotes in a pattern in 300k lines. I'm trying to use sed and I read multiple inquiries here and other sources, but I can't seem to understand its syntax.

I have:

```
chr1    StringTie       exon    191964  192299  1000    -       .       gene_id MSTRG.201; transcript_id MSTRG.201.53; exon_number 2;
chrY    StringTie       exon    26420508        26420531        1000    +       .       gene_id MSTRG.49889; transcript_id MSTRG.49889.11; exon_number 1;
```

And I need to have:

```
chr1    StringTie       exon    191964  192299  1000    -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.201"; transcript_id "MSTRG.201.53"; exon_number 2;
chrY    StringTie       exon    26420508        26420531        1000    +       .       gene_id "MSTRG.49889"; transcript_id "MSTRG.49889.11"; exon_number 1;
```

I'm using sed as follows:

```
sed 's/MSTRG./"MSTRG."/g' filename
```

But I can only get:

```
chr1    StringTie       exon    191964  192299  1000    -       .       gene_id "MSTRG."201; transcript_id "MSTRG."201.53; exon_number 2;
chrY    StringTie       exon    26420508        26420531        1000    +       .       gene_id "MSTRG."49889; transcript_id "MSTRG."49889.11; exon_number 1;
```

I've tried:

```
sed -Ei 's|MSTRG[[:digit:]]+|"&"|g' filename
sed 's/M/"M/; s/$/"/' filename
sed 's/MSTRG.[[:digit:]]+/"MSTRG.[[:digit:]]+"/g' filename
```

But none of these will work.

I was wondering if I could use awk, but I don't have any skills in this language.

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic and welcome here, but based on your input file, you might also be interested in checking out our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 5):

Why limit yourself to this particular gene name? Here's a more general solution that will put anything after `gene_id` or `transcript_id` and until the first `;` in quotes:

```
$ sed -E 's/(transcript_id|gene_id)  *([^;]+)/\1 "\2"/g' file
chr1    StringTie       exon    191964  192299  1000    -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.201"; transcript_id "MSTRG.201.53"; exon_number 2;
chrY    StringTie       exon    26420508        26420531        1000    +       .       gene_id "MSTRG.49889"; transcript_id "MSTRG.49889.11"; exon_number 1;
```

#### Explanation

- `-E`: this enables extended regular expressions which let us use `( )` unescaped (not `\( \)`) to *capture* groups, and also gives us `+` for "one or more" and allows us to use unescaped `|` for "either this or that".
- `s/(transcript_id|gene_id)  *([^;]+)/\1"\2"/g'`: we are looking for either `transcript_id` or `gene_id` (that's why the `|` is used, for "OR"), followed by one or more spaces ( `+`), and then one or more non-`;` characters. The parentheses are used to *capture* what is matched, so it can then be used on the right hand side of the substitution operator. The first captured group (here, the `transcript_id` or `gene_id` along with the spaces) will be `\1`, the second will be `\2` and so on. Then, this is all replaced with whatever was captured first (`\1`) and then whatever was captured second, surrounded by quotes (`"\2"`).
- `s///g`: the `g` is needed to make the substitution **g**lobal, to substitute all matches found on the same line. Without the `g`, only the first match would be substituted.

You can use this on arbitrary gene names, even an entire GTF file and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/MSTRG[0-9.]+/"&"/g' file
```

Output:

```
chr1    StringTie       exon    191964  192299  1000    -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.201"; transcript_id "MSTRG.201.53"; exon_number 2;
chrY    StringTie       exon    26420508        26420531        1000    +       .       gene_id "MSTRG.49889"; transcript_id "MSTRG.49889.11"; exon_number 1;
```

> **&**: refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Making use of `;` which seems consistent .... `sed 's/MSTRG.[^;]*/"&"/g'` might be a shorter alternative ... Also, most likely the extended regex flag `-E` won't be needed.

Comment: The `;` is consistent, yes: the OP didn't mention it, but this is [GTF or GFF](https://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html?redirect=no), standard formats in bioinformatics.